# When should a method be declared synchronized?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-synchronization

Following is a, simple, working program which uses two threads to print a counter:

```
public class SynchronizedCounter implements Runnable {

    private static int i = 0;

    public void increment() { i++; }
    public int getValue() { return i; }  

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
            synchronized( this ) {
                increment();
                System.out.println( Thread.currentThread().getName() + " counter: " + this.getValue() );
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) {

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 2 );
        SynchronizedCounter synchronizedCounter = new SynchronizedCounter();
        executorService.submit( synchronizedCounter );
        executorService.submit( synchronizedCounter );  
        executorService.shutdown();

    }

}
```

The output is as expected - the two threads display counter in order.

If `increment()` and `getValue()` are declared as `synchronized` and `synchronized` block code is commented, the output manifests visibility and race problems.

As `increment()` and `getValue()` are not declared as `synchronized` and by, just, using a `synchronized` block(passing a monitor object) if synchronization could be achieved, in what circumstances should they be declared as `synchronized`?

Comment: I agree with atomicity but, even without methods being synchronized, other threads can call in between. Isn't it? Help me understand.

Comment: I would not ever submit the same object to an Executor more than one time. Even if it works,... Even if I can prove that it is always _supposed_ to work,... There's eventually going to be somebody who needs to read my code, and I don't want that person to have to search in reference manuals and/or library source code to prove to themselves that it will work.

Comment: When you run that, I bet you see one thread finish printing five lines before the other even starts.  The reason is, after the loop in your `run()` method unlocks `this`, the _very next thing_ that it does is lock it again. Intrinsic locks in Java are not _fair_. When two or more threads await a _fair_ lock, the winner always is the one that's been waiting the longest.  But, when two or more threads await a Java intrinsic lock, the winner will be whichever thread can grab it first. In this case, that will be the thread that's already running, not the one that went to sleep, waiting for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `increment()` method uses `i++` which is in fact substituted by 3 instructions. If that method is not declared as `synchronized` then several threads may execute it at the same time which will lead to race conditions and incorrect results.

> If increment() and getValue() are declared as synchronized and
>   synchronized block code is commented, the output manifests visibility
>   and race problems.

There are no race conditions in this case. You see different results because now `increment()` and `getValue()` are not executed atomically (by atomically I mean two methods as one synch block) and while one thread called `increment()` and is about to call `getValue()` another thread also called `increment()`.

So you need to make `increment()` and `getValue()` synchronized if you are planning to call them outside of `synchronized` block in your `run` method (and because they are declared as `public` there is a possibility to make such calls).

Comment: AndyTurner and assylias, your answers, too, gave insights. I had ▲ your answers too.

Comment: I'm confused by your statement - "There are no race conditions in this case". But, the code has two threads and, I think, they doing the same as you mentioned in first paragraph - "If that method is not declared as synchronized then several threads may execute it at the same time which will lead to race conditions and incorrect results". Help me understand the contradiction.

Comment: @user1418717 since i++ is in fact 3 operations then if method is not synched then calling it from 2 threads for the same time may lead to missing update and i will have value 1 instead of 2. if `increment()` is synched then there will be no race conditions for update of i. If you remove `synchronized(this)` from for-loop then it will be possible that first thread calls increment the second calls increment and then first calls getValue which will return 2 instead of 1 but that will be correct behavior since increment was called twice.

Comment: I got you. One more question which I tried getting from Net but, I didn't find a clear and direct answer or may be I have confusion in understanding, anyways, the question - while a thread is executing a instance method, can another thread execute a static method and vice versa?

Comment: Of none or only one is synchronized then yes. If both are synchronized (like synchronized methods) then also yes because for static method MyClass.class will be a monitor and for instance method instance on which you call method will be a monitor. But it is also possible to add the following synch block into instance method `synchronized (MyClass.class) {}` in that case it would be impossible to execute both static synch method and that synch block inside instance method at the same time

Comment: Your approach to solve a problem and explanation is excellent.

Answer (score 5):

Declare a method synchronized when you need the semantics of a synchronized block around the body of the method.

```
synchronized void increment() {
  ...
}
```

is exactly the same as:

```
void increment() {
  synchronized (this) { ... }
}
```

The thing about doing that in the code above is that you no longer execute the `increment()` and `getValue()` methods atomically: another thread can nip in and execute the methods in between the calls of your thread:

```
Thread 1             Thread 2

increment()
                     increment()
                     getValue()
getValue()
```

This is possible, but two threads can't execute `increment()` (or `getValue()`) at the same time, because they are synchronized (*).

On the other hand, synchronizing around the calls as in the code in the question means that the two calls are executed atomically, so the two threads can't interleave:

```
Thread 1             Thread 2

increment()
getValue()
                     increment()
                     getValue()
```

---

(*) Actually, they can both be executing the method at the same time. It's just that all but one of the threads will be waiting at the `synchronized (this)`.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, the class itself is not thread safe and it is up to the client (your `run` method) to ensure thread safety.

If you want to make the class thread safe such that clients don't need to do anything particular to use it, it should have proper synchronization mechanisms and propose "higher level" method that can run atomic operation on a combination of operations if necessary.

Think of `AtomicInteger`, for example, which has an `incrementAndGet()` method that would provide a superior approach. Your `run` method would then become:

```
for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
  int newValue = counter.incrementAndGet();
  System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " counter: " + newValue );
}
```